# Why does changing a property of a reference variable in an object changes that object's memory address?

Tags: java, hashcode, cloning

We have the Person class, with 3 variables, "firstName", "lastName" (both String) and "Address" address. Address class has 2 properties, "cityName" and "countryName" (both String).

Having instantiated a new Person object and given values to each property, when one changed the value "cityName" of the "address" property of the Person object, this change did not only change the hashcode of the address property, but it did for the person object as well.

Shouldn't the only change be the hashcode of the "cityName" property?

Here is the code:

```
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Person implements Cloneable
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Address address;

    public Person(Person personToBeCloned) {
        Address clonedAddress = personToBeCloned.getAddress();

        this.firstName = personToBeCloned.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = personToBeCloned.getLastName();
        this.address = new Address(clonedAddress.getStreetName(), clonedAddress.getCityName());
    }
    
    @Override
    public Person clone()  {
        try {
            return (Person) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", address=" + address + "] " +
                this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "@" + this.hashCode();
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Address implements Cloneable
{
    private String streetName;
    private String cityName;

    @Override
    public Address clone() {
        try
        {
            return (Address) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException cloneException)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(cloneException);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address [streetName=" + streetName + ", cityName=" + cityName + "] "
            + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "@" + this.hashCode();
    }
}
```

**Here is the test being run and in the console, one can see that Person and Address change their in-memory address.**

```
    @Test
    public void shallowCopy()
    {
        Person shallowCopyOfAlex = alex.clone();

        System.out.println("Details before change:");
        System.out.println(alex);
        System.out.println(shallowCopyOfAlex);

        assertEquals(alex, shallowCopyOfAlex);

        alex.getAddress().setCityName("Unknown City");

        System.out.println("\nDetails after change:");
        System.out.println(alex);
        System.out.println(shallowCopyOfAlex);

        assertEquals(alex.getAddress(), shallowCopyOfAlex.getAddress());
    }
```

```
Details before change:
Person [firstName=Alex, lastName=Jones, address=Address [streetName=Main Street, cityName=Main City] Address@-1825014247] Person@932142263
Person [firstName=Alex, lastName=Jones, address=Address [streetName=Main Street, cityName=Main City] Address@-1825014247] Person@932142263

Details after change:
Person [firstName=Alex, lastName=Jones, address=Address [streetName=Main Street, cityName=Unknown City] Address@-437944728] Person@-1975755514
Person [firstName=Alex, lastName=Jones, address=Address [streetName=Main Street, cityName=Unknown City] Address@-437944728] Person@-1975755514
```

Comment: Your question title and last part suggest that you think "memory address" and "hashcode" are synonyms. They're really not. It makes perfect sense to me that changing some aspect of the address of a person would change the hash code of a person, once you understand the purpose of a hash code. Do you think the address *shouldn't* contribute to the hash code, even though it *does* contribute to equality?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, when you want to learn about details of `hashCode` then it's probably a good idea to avoid Lombok, because it hides all its code from you. Just let your IDE generate those methods and you'll get very similar behaviour to what Lombok does, but you'll be able to *see and understand* what it does.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, that is correct. I understand, that makes sense now. So even though it IS the same object, the hashcode has changed.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks for the heads up, I have updated the question. I wasn't even thinking that it could be related to the hashcode, but now it's all like "d'uuuhhhh". lol

Comment: The hashcode has nothing to do with memory address, and nothing to do with object identity. It has everything to do with object contents.

Comment: FWIW java does offer a way to find the address by using the class [Unsafe](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/misc/Unsafe.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: no, it's shouldn't, because the hashCode function (create via lombok) consider all your fields, when a field value change, hashCode change accordingly.

If you de-lombok your pojos, you'll see that hashCode method simply consider the hashCodes of all your fields; so, for any field that changes, doesn't matter at what level, hashCode change too

```
package org.example;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public class HashCodeExplanation {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Person {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private Address address;

        public boolean equals(final Object o) {
            ...
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            final int PRIME = 59;
            int result = 1;
            final Object $firstName = this.getFirstName();
            result = result * PRIME + ($firstName == null ? 43 : $firstName.hashCode());
            final Object $lastName = this.getLastName();
            result = result * PRIME + ($lastName == null ? 43 : $lastName.hashCode());
            final Object $address = this.getAddress();
            result = result * PRIME + ($address == null ? 43 : $address.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Address {
        private String cityName;
        private String countryName;

        public boolean equals(final Object o) {
            ...
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            final int PRIME = 59;
            int result = 1;
            final Object $cityName = this.getCityName();
            result = result * PRIME + ($cityName == null ? 43 : $cityName.hashCode());
            final Object $countryName = this.getCountryName();
            result = result * PRIME + ($countryName == null ? 43 : $countryName.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Super, thanks for the answer! One question though: if the hashcode changes, does this mean the in memory address has changed too ? We're still referring to the same object, correct? Just with 1 variable changed.

Comment: @Art Java doesn't make any guarantees about the memory address. That is a detail you're not supposed to worry about. The object could change address, without anything being changed. Have you read through  the hashCode method [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) ?

Comment: And just to further hark on the distinction: The hash code is unrelated to the memory address. The memory address itself is also unrelated to "where your reference points" in an un-intuitive sense: **If** the VM decided that moving the object in-memory was a good idea, then such a change would necessarily be 100% transparent to Java code, i.e. all reference that point to that object would continue doing so. From the Java perspective, there *is no memory address*, it's an implementation detail that you don't see.

Comment: @matt ah, I see! Very interesting, did not know that. I had not, but will read it now, thanks!